# PDF Viewer in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, pdf

I'm looking for a good PDF viewer for SharePoint 2010. We have a lot of PDFs in our document library and we'd like to have a viewer embedded in SP instead of relying on the user's external PDF viewer. I found one at www.knowledgelake.com. Does anyone know of any others available or have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [Flash based PDF Viewers](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&xhr=t&q=flash+based+pdf+viewer&cp=0&pf=p&sclient=psy&site=webhp&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=flash+based+pdf+v&pbx=1&fp=ba7fef54647adf37&ion=1) or [Silverlight based ones](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=webhp&q=silverlight++pdf+viewer&aq=f&aqi=g1g-m2&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=ba7fef54647adf37&ion=1).